# ./bash: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to connect to my SSH server with a customized `sshd_config` file.
But when I try to connect, it gives the following error:

./bash: No such file or directory

And I copied bash to their directory including `/bin`, `/lib64` and `/lib`.

These are the lines I added to sshd_config:

```
Match User cooluser
ChrootDirectory /home/cooluser
```

The /home/cooluser directory also exists.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `ChrootDirectory` directive? That means "use this as the root directory under which everything else should be found". Since you presumably don't have things like `/home/cooluser/bin` or `/home/cooluser/lib` etc., this is almost certainly not what you want to do. Please [edit] your question and explain what your final objective is, tell us why you are modifying the ssh config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are choosing to set up a chroot jail for the user that logs in. That means that you give that user his own private root directory, distinct from the system root. Accordingly, you will have to setup the interactive shell for that chroot environment. Among many other things, that involves having a `/home/cooluser/bin` directory. When logging in under that configuration, that directory is seen as `bin` because `/home/cooluser` has been set to be `/` with your `chrootDirectory /home/cooluser` statement.

You probably want to look for an easier solution, or read up a bit more about the approach you are taking now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to change directory, it should be `cd ./bash`. Otherwise it would just say if the directory exists or not (Or execute an executable file called `bash` if it exists). Also the `./` part of `./bash` means that you are looking at the folder `bash` from your working directory.
If you want the path from home use `~/bash` instead.

Why are you copying bash to `/bin` and the other ones? I assume bash is preinstalled on Ubuntu based distros. It is the default one in the terminal.

I'm not familiar with SSH yet so I can't help with SSH configuration.

Comment: I am copying bash to their home directory because else it also said /bin/bash was not found

Comment: And yes bash exists, because I can see it in my FTP

Comment: Can you define your problem better? Bash is a binary that is in `/usr/bin`. Why would you need a folder called bash?

Comment: I do not have a folder called bash, it is a file in the users home directory, it is also in /usr/bin or /bin but i copied it because it gives an error (probably because of ChrootDirectory).

Comment: Sorry for some reason I thought it is a folder. If you can see the file in your file manager press `ctrl + L` and use the absolute path instead.

I wish I can help more but I am also relatively new to Linux.